# Python Script for Monthly Recurring Expenses

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to use Python to generate a csv displaying monthly expense data for 5 employees.  The following is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv
import math

emp_id = 0
year = 2017
start_month = 1
months_to_add = 12
Amount = 50.00
emp_per_month = 5
output_file = 'Monthly.csv'

def format_emp_id(id):
    return "E%03d" % (id,)

with open(output_file, 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile,
                        delimiter='\t',
                        quotechar='"',
                        quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    writer.writerow(['ID', 'Date', 'Amount'])

    for month in range(start_month, months_to_add + 1):
        date = "%d-%02.d-%02.d" % (year, month, 1)
        for install in range(int(emp_per_month)):
            emp_id += 1
            writer.writerow([format_emp_id(emp_id), date, Amount])
        emp_per_month = 5
```

However, this code gives me the following output:

```
 ID  |    Date    |  Amount   |
E001 | 2015-01-01 |   50.00   |
E002 | 2015-01-01 |   50.00   |
E003 | 2015-01-01 |   50.00   |
E004 | 2015-01-01 |   50.00   |
E005 | 2015-01-01 |   50.00   |
E006 | 2015-02-01 |   50.00   |
E007 | 2015-02-01 |   50.00   |
E008 | 2015-02-01 |   50.00   |
E009 | 2015-02-01 |   50.00   |
E010 | 2015-02-01 |   50.00   |
```

However, this is not what I need it to do.  What I need is for Employee ID E001-E005 to repeat every month, not continue incrementing Employee IDs past E005.

Please advise me on the revisions needed to correct this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
emp_id = 1
```

at the start of your for loop. This resets the id value each monch, so that every month it begins at one.

Answer (score 1):

I'd change your innermost `for` loop to this:

```
for emp_id in range(1, emp_per_month+1):
    writer.writerow([format_emp_id(emp_id), date, Amount])
```